# Swift 2.0 Tuple pattern element label must be '_'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have been trying to fix all my code since swift 2.0 update. I have a problem that seems to be the way tuples work now:

```
public func generate() -> AnyGenerator <(String, JSON)> {
    switch self.type {
    case .Array:
        let array_ = object as! [AnyObject]
        var generate_ = array_.generate()
        var index_: Int = 0
        return anyGenerator{
            if let element_: AnyObject = generate_.next() {
                return ("\(index_++)", JSON(element_))
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    case .Dictionary:
        let dictionary_ = object as! [String : AnyObject]
        var generate_ = dictionary_.generate()
        return anyGenerator{
            if let (key_: String, value_: AnyObject) = generate_.next() {
                return (key_, JSON(value_))
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    default:
        return anyGenerator{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically the line:

```
if let (key_: String, value_: AnyObject) = generate_.next()
```

Is throwing the error: Tuple pattern element label 'key' must be '_'

I tried to make that change already, but I didnt work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is: We cannot use type annotation *inside* of tuple patterns **anymore**.

In the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html):

> Type annotations are no longer allowed in patterns and are considered part of the outlying declaration. This means that code previously written as:
>
> ```
> var (a : Int, b : Float) = foo()
> ```
>
> needs to be written as:
>
> ```
> var (a,b) : (Int, Float) = foo()
> ```
>
> if an explicit type annotation is needed. The former syntax was ambiguous with tuple element labels. (20167393)

So, you can:

```
if let (key_, value_): (String, AnyObject) = generate_.next() {
```

But in this case, you could omit `: (String, AnyObject)`:

```
if let (key_, value_) = generate_.next() {
```

Comment: Yes, this caught me too and I asked Apple about it. The change is deliberate. I liked the other notation, but the change is no big deal really...